# About Powell lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, optical-materials

I am a Post graduation student and I am doing a project on the conversion of a Gaussian beam into a flat top beam using optical components. I have found that the best component to do the same is a Powell lens. I would like to know more about the equations connecting the input beam diameter, output beam diameter, wavelength of the light and the fan angle of a Powell lens.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to contact their inventor and company that makes them: http://www.laserlineoptics.com/specifications.html  they could tell you everything you need.